# In .NET how do I ignore end tags in an XML comparison?

Tags: .net, xml, comparison

I am attempting to compare two .NET strings that contain xml

```
<FIRST_NAME type="CHAR" />
```

and

```
<FIRST_NAME type="CHAR"></FIRST_NAME>
```

If I compare them as they are (as strings) it results in false. I want the comparison to result in true, since in XML they are functionally the same thing. What do I need to do so that a comparison of these two items (and others like it, where the difference is an end tag missing, or being present) return true?

Note, casting into an XML object/type of some sort from a string is fine, as long as the end result is a function/method that returns true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML Digital Signatures capability built into .NET includes a class called [XmlDsigC14NTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigc14ntransform.aspx) , whose purpose is to transform XML into a canonical representation so that two blocks can be compared for equality.  It will, among other things, normalize self-terminated elements.  You can read [more about the various forms of canonicalization it supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedinfo.canonicalizationmethod.aspx).

So, you would parse both strings into two `XmlDocument` instances, run each through the transform (`LoadInput/GetOutput`), and then compare the two outputs:

```
        void Test()
        {
            string xml1 = @"<FIRST_NAME type=""CHAR"" />";
            string xml2 = @"<FIRST_NAME type='CHAR'></FIRST_NAME>";
            bool areEqual = Compare(xml1,xml2);
        }

        bool Compare(string xml1, string xml2)
        {            
            return Canonicalize(xml1).Equals(Canonicalize(xml2));            
        }

        string Canonicalize(string xml)
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            var xmlTransform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform(true) { Algorithm = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl };
            xmlTransform.LoadInput(doc);
            using( var stream = (Stream)xmlTransform.GetOutput(typeof(Stream)))
            {
                var docOut = new XmlDocument();
                docOut.Load(stream);
                return docOut.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
            }
        }
```

Comment: could you provide an example from string to xml comparison yielding true? Im having a hard time following the example documentation on the msdn website.

Comment: Added code sample.  Note how it deals with the difference between single and double quotes around the attribute values as well.

Comment: awesome, trying it now, thanks. what does the "{algorithm...}" line do?

Comment: See the 2nd hyperlink from the answer above.  It controls exactly set of rules is used for canonicalization (whether XML comments are included, among other things)

Answer (score 0):

use **Microsoft XML Diff**: see these links:

- [Using the XML Diff and Patch Tool in Your Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)
- [The XML Diff and Patch GUI Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse both documents and compare the resulting document nodes using the XPath 2.0 (or XQuery 1.0) deep-equal() function.